# Building a more efficient SQL insert with StringBuffer

Tags: java, sql

I'm working on a project and I've created a method `insertStatement()` which creates a string buffer that structures my SQL insert statement. Here it is:

```
private String insertStatement() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(
            "insert into CUSTOMER (NAME, NUMBER, CITY, STATE) values (");
    sb.append("'" + this.custName + "',");
    sb.append("'" + this.custNum + "',");
    sb.append("'" + this.custCity + "',");
    sb.append("'" + this.custState + ")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of building this statement without having to append each line with a `'` at the start and a `',` at the end.

Some more detail for the question. I am creating a batch job and this method is returning the statement as a String which will then populate an Array List that will be passed to an ItemWriter, which then stores the data into the database.

Comment: Yes, use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and don't leave yourself open to SQL injection.

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot use something such as a `PreparedStatement`? Then you could do something like `PreparedStatement pstmt = databaseConnection.prepareStatement("insert into Customer (name, number, city, state) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?)");` and then afterwards replace with pstmt.setString(1, this.custName); etc

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience working with databases, so I didn't know `PreparedStatement` was an option! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ever use `StringBuffer`. It's been replaced by `StringBuilder`. Use `PreparedStatement`; it's type safe and prevents SQL injection attacks.

If you do use `StringBuilder` to build strings, as it is intended, don't do inline string concatenation within the `append` sequence; just use `append`.

As to prepending (not "appending") a quote and appending quote-comma, that is an artifact of building an unsafe SQL string, and is inescapable in that context. `PreparedStatement` will handle that for you.

Comment: This makes sense, and I was looking at this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm) and I see that they're connecting to a database. I'm simply constructing the statement to be passed back into an ArrayList of the statements, which will then be passed into an ItemWriter (which will write to the database). So I was wondering if I should follow this procedure still?

Answer (score 1):

Your Code, highlighted(using **) string instances in memory:

```
    private String insertStatement() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(
            **"insert into CUSTOMER (NAME, NUMBER, CITY, STATE) values ("**);
    sb.append(**"'"** + this.custName + **"',"**);
    sb.append(**"'"** + this.custNum + **"',"**);
    sb.append(**"'"** + this.custCity + **"',"**);
    sb.append(**"'"** + this.custState + **")"**);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Counting the variables this.custName, this.custNum etc. you have in total (4 String variables + 4 "'" + 4 "'," + 4 string instances that you create when concatenating stuff + 1 string builder instance ) = 17 string object instances in memory at the time this function is called.

```
        private String insertStatement() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(
            "insert into CUSTOMER (NAME, NUMBER, CITY, STATE) values (");
    String quote = "'";
    String endQuoteComma = "',";
    String endingBracket = ")";
    sb.append(quote);    
    sb.append(this.custName);
    sb.append(endQuoteComma);
    sb.append(quote);
    sb.append(this.custNum);
    sb.append(endQuoteComma);
    sb.append(quote);
    sb.append(this.custCity);
    sb.append(endQuoteComma);
    sb.append(quote);
    sb.append(this.custState);
    sb.append(endingBracket);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This version will create 8 instances of string in memory, 4 variables + 3 quote, endquotecomma,endbracket variables + 1 string buffer instance

Why?
Because strings are immutable, you cannot change or modify a string once you have created it.

Does it matter here? probably not, unless you are calling it a million times within a loop, that would create 17 * million approx. instances in memory string objects and you may end up running out of memory.

I also think the comments are quite valid and you should use Prepared Statement in this case. Just wanted to highlight the advantage of using a string buffer.